# How do I align RichText to bottom center of screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, but it's not working. From the class I took to do this, all he had was a sized box to fit it at the bottom of the screen. But that isn't working for different screen sizes..

Here is everything inside SingleChildScrollView. RichText is near the bottom. (Changed from register screen to my login screen because it has less code).

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 45, horizontal: 50),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 50),
            Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/image.jpg'),
            ),
            
            SizedBox(height: 50),

             TextFormField(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              controller: emailController,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter Email",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFD6D6D6)),
                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
             ),

            SizedBox(height: 4),

            TextFormField(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              controller: passwordController,
              obscureText: isHiddenPassword,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter Password",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFD6D6D6)),
                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                suffixIcon: InkWell(
                  onTap: _togglePasswordView,
                  child: Icon(
                      isHiddenPassword
                          ? Icons.visibility_outlined
                          : Icons.visibility_off_outlined,
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
    
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(

                minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(40),
                primary: Colors.white,
              ),
              
              child: Text(
                'Sign In',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Color(0xFF162242)),
              
              ),
              onPressed: signIn, 
            ),
            
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            SignInButton(
              Buttons.Facebook, onPressed: () {},
              text: "Sign in with Facebook",
              ),

              SizedBox(height: 16),

            SignInButton(
              Buttons.Google,
              text: "Sign in with Google",
              onPressed: () {
                signInWithGoogle();
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            GestureDetector(
              child: Text(
                'Forgot Password?',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 18,
                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                          color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ForgotPasswordPage(),
              )),
            ),
            // SizedBox(
            //   height: 100),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFD6D6D6), fontSize: 20),
                  text: 'No account?  ',
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                        ..onTap = widget.onClickedSignUp,
                      text: 'Sign Up',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: could you share an image of the current output?

Comment: also could you share your column code too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Spacer` to push the child till the end of the `Column` like so:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
    Container(
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Spacer(),
    RichText(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      text: TextSpan(
        text: 'Already have an account?',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        children: [
          TextSpan(
            text: 'Sign In',
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```